# How To Use Getters And Setters In PHP With User Input

Tags: php, mysql, getter-setter

I have created a registration form and now I want to insert data by using Getters and Setters. I have created `intAll.php` file which has HTML structure and PHP function, then I have created `Encap.php` file which has Database Connection, My SQL Queries and Getters/Setters. Now I want to pass my Input Data to `Encap.php` file and I want to catch them in `Encap.php` file and insert into My SQL DB, but my codes don't work.

So, How to Fix this?

> intAll.php File

```
<?php  

 include 'Encap.php';  
 $InsertData = new Databases; 

 $success_message = '';  
 if(isset($_POST["submit"]))  
 {  

    $InsertData->setName($_POST['name']);
    $InsertData->setUsername($_POST['username']);
    $InsertData->setPassword($_POST['password']);

    //$name=$_POST['name'];
    //$username=$_POST['username'];
    //$password=$_POST['password'];

      if($InsertData->insertsingle())  
      {  
           $success_message = 'Post Inserted';  
      }       
 }  
 ?>  
 <!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html>  
      <head>  
           <title>Insert data into Table using OOPS in PHP</title>  
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
           <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
      </head>  
      <body>  
           <br /><br />  
           <div class="container" style="width:700px;">  
                <form method="post">  
                     <label>Name</label>  
                     <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" />  
                     <br />  
                     <label>Username</label>  
                     <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" />  
                     <br /> 
                     <label>Password</label>  
                     <input type="text" name="password" class="form-control" />  
                     <br />
                     <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />  
                     <span class="text-success">  
                     <?php  
                     if(isset($success_message))  
                     {  
                          echo $success_message;  
                     }  
                     ?>  
                     </span>  
                </form>  
           </div>  
      </body>  
 </html>
```

> Encap.php File

```
<?php   

 class Databases{  
      public $con;  

      private $id;
      private $name;
      private $username;
      private $password;

      function setId($id) { 
          $this->id = $id; 
          }

      function getId() {
          return $this->id; 
          }

      function setName($name) { 
          $this->name = $name; 
          }

      function getName() { 
          return $this->name; 
          }

      function setUsername($username) { 
          $this->username = $username; 
          }

      function getUsername() { 
          return $this->username; 
          }

      function setPassword($password) { 
          $this->password = $password; 
          }

      function getPassword() { 
          return $this->password; 
          }

      public function __construct()  
      {  
           $this->con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "portal");  
           if(!$this->con)  
           {  
                echo 'Database Connection Error ' . mysqli_connect_error($this->con);  
           }  
      }

        public function insertsingle()  
      {  
           $string = "INSERT INTO academic (name,username,pw) VALUES ('getName()','getUserName()','getPassword()')";
           $rsint=mysqli_query($this->con, $string);  
           return $rsint;
      }

 }  
 ?>
```

Comment: What does it insert ? getName() ?

Comment: What isn't working? Are you getting an error message (and if so, what is the error)? At first glance, it looks like your `Databases` class does not have an `insert()` method. **Edit** At second glance, it looks like your `insertsingle()` method should be using a prepared statement.

Comment: @SaadSuri - yh , thats what I want to know.. I want to figure it out..

Comment: Why are you making another database wrapper? There is a `MySQLi` class in php. Use it.

Comment: @rickdenhaan - I fixed it..

Comment: @tereško - I didn't understand it.. How to do it ?

Comment: it's very pointless to do it this way. First of, make up your mind what Databases is supposed to represent: a database connection or a gateway to a specific table (academic). Then consider not using getters and setters on that class, but just have insertSingle accept the data you want to insert. When you realized it's really Table Data Gateway, you'll also realize that having setters and getters for individual rows on it, doesn't make much sense. So get rid of them and just pass the individual scalar values to insertSingle instead.

Comment: @Gordon - So, U mean just pass the data from intAll.php function to Encap.php insertSingle function ??

Comment: Yes. Just pass them directly

Comment: @Gordon - Okay , Thank U Bro !! :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot call a function within in a string. You should interrupt your string to do that:

```
public function insertsingle()  
{  
     $string = "INSERT INTO academic (name,username,pw) VALUES ('" . $this->getName() . "','" . $this->getUserName() . "','" . $this->getPassword() . "')";
     $rsint=mysqli_query($this->con, $string);  
     return $rsint;
}
```

However, since you're not sanitizing your user input anywhere, this code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks and you should be using a prepared statement instead (note: untested code, might need to be tweaked a little):

```
public function insertsingle()  
{  
     $string = "INSERT INTO academic (name,username,pw) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
     $stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->con, $string);
     $stmt->bind_param("sss", $this->getName(), $this->getUserName(), $this->getPassword());
     $rsint = $stmt->execute();
     return $rsint;
}
```

Comment: Just typing this and find your answer. Ah miss my points again on comments

Comment: @SaadSuri happens to me all the time ;-)

Comment: @rickdenhaan - 100% Perfectly worked first one !! 
Thank U Very Much !! :D

Comment: @rickdenhaan - But, when I use second one , it gives me a error " Warning: mysqli_stmt::prepare() expects exactly 1 parameter, 4 given in C:\wamp\www\newOOP\Encap.php on line 56 "

Comment: @KistlakRajapaksha change `$stmt->prepare` to [`$stmt->bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Comment: Ah yes, that should be `bind_param`, let me update my answer

Comment: Still , gives me an error - "  Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\wamp\www\newOOP\Encap.php on line 56 "

Comment: Like I said, "untested" ;-) That warning means you'll need to drop the three function calls into a variable first, e.g. `$name = $this->getName();` and then use `$name` in the call to `bind_param()`

Comment: @rickdenhaan - Great Work , Its working !! Thank You Bro !! :D

Comment: @rickdenhaan - if I use getters and setters like this , is it a bad practice ? Or I can directly pass the variables from intAll.php to Encap.php insertSingle function. Is this a good or bad practice ??

Comment: Depends on your use case. In my opinion, this is fine if you want to add extra logic like data validation to your setters or lazy instantiation (or default values) to your getters. But opinions differ on the subject.

Comment: @rickdenhaan - Okay , Thank U Very Much Bro !! :D